# Upload pict with ASIHttpRequest. iPhone client / node.js server

Tags: node.js, asihttprequest, express

On client side I use ASIHttpRequest to upload a pict:

```
// upload on server
NSLog(@"Upload to server");
UIImage *im = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ok.png"];
NSData *da = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(im, 0.6);
NSLog(@"DATA:%@", da);

NSString *n =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/upload", @"http://localhost:3000"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:n];
NSLog(@"URL:%@",url);
ASIFormDataRequest *r = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

[r setData:da 
withFileName:@"myphoto.ico" 
andContentType:@"image/jpeg"
      forKey:@"photo"];
[r setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[r setShouldAttemptPersistentConnection:NO];
[r startSynchronous];
NSString *resp = [r responseString];
NSLog(@"RESPONSE:%@", resp);
```

On server side, I use node.js:

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res){
    console.log(req);
    console.log(req.params);
});
```

The request on client side seems ok but when checking the log on server side I do not see any things linked to the data I sent. What is the correct way to retrieve the data on node.js in this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Connect-Form and req.form.completed did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking for req.files, see the official example from Connect (which is used internally by Express): https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/examples/bodyParser.js#L21-31

Comment: What version of Express are you using?

Comment: I have upgraded to espress 2.5.1. req.files.length gives 0 and req.files.image is undefined.

Comment: I'm 0 at iPhone native programming, so .. are you sure you are correctly sending the picture..?

Comment: youmight be right but honnestly it seems ok according to the doc.

Comment: Ok, to test this use the basic example of node-formidable (which is used by express under the hood): https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable/tree/master/example